# What is a good naming convention for Periodic Snapshot Fact Tables?

Tags: database-design, ssas, data-warehouse

I'm looking for a good naming convention for my period snapshot fact tables.

Currently, I'm just appending "_Snapshot" onto the end of the name used for the underlying transactional fact table.  Here's an example...

```
FactWorkOrder (Transactional)
FactWorkOrder_SnapshotWkly (Weekly Snapshot)
```

I realize naming conventions are subjective, but that doesn't mean there aren't accepted preferences.

For example, most microsoft material uses proper case, no space or underscore...

```
TableName.ColumnName
```

instead of ...

```
TABLENAME.COLUMNNAME
TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME
[TABLE NAME].[COLUMN NAME]
```

And most Kimball material uses Dim or D, Fact or F prepending...

```
DimDate
FactWorkOrder
```

even underscores...

```
D_Date
F_WorkOrder
```

unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anything on snapshot tables.

Comment: Naming conventions are very subjective so I don't think that this question is even on topic, strictly speaking. Simply pick something that works with your existing naming convention and is clear. My only comment on your example is to spell out "Weekly" fully, it makes no sense to shorten the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kimball's book he uses WorkOrderSnapshotFact etc. So using the word "Snapshot" seems like a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my naming convention for period snapshot fact tables:

1) Since a periodic snapshot always holds a defined period of time,
    this time-range should definitely be in name of the snapshot.

Examples:

```
FactWorkOrder_SnapshotWeekly
   FactWorkOrder_SnapshotMonthly
```

2)    Since the periodic snapshot table is dependent on the transactional fact
    table, this should also be reflected in the naming.

Examples:

The base fact:

```
FactWorkOrder
```

and the snapshot:

```
FactWorkOrder_SnapshotWeekly
```

3) If you have fact table with different grains you could consider specifying the grain of the fact table in the name

Examples:

```
FactWorkOrder_Atomic
   FactWorkOrder_AggregatedOnMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

OD_MD_[subject area name] --- MD for Master dimension

OD_MH_[subject area name] --- MH for hierarchical 
OD_FB_[subject area name] ---FB for FACT base table which stores non aggregated data           like transaction,purchases.
OD_FC_[subject area name] ---FB for FACT calculated table which stores Metrics and aggreagted KPI

OD_FB_SN_[subject area name] - Snapshot
OD_FB_WK_[subject area name] Weekly snapshot base table